# HTML translation for Google Apps Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am using a WYSIWYG editor to create a template for the html I would like for a container bound UI.

I know nothing about html.

I do know that google apps script(GAS) will not accept head/body shenanigans. I want to take:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p><strong>Welcome to the project workflow environment!</strong></p>

<p>Please start by defining your project name.</p>

<p><input name="txtProjectName" type="text" /></p>

<p>&nbsp;<input name="cmdProjectSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" /></p>

<p>--------------------------------------------------------------</p>

<p>Please define your project starting point.</p>

<p><select name="cbPhase" size="1"><option value="0">Sales</option><option value="1">Operations ( Quote/ROM/BOM)</option><option value="2">Design Engineering</option><option value="3">Construction</option><option value="4">System Performance Engineering</option><option value="5">Maintenance</option></select></p>

<p><input name="cmdPhaseSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" /></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and turn it into something GAS will accept.

Here is an example of what GAS is looking for.... No head/body shenanigans.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div>
<span>Let's get started with your workflow. First add an approver by entering their email address in the Approvers box and clicking the add button. When you are done adding approvers, click the Start Workflow button.</span>
</div> 
<br>
<div>
<span class="sectionHeader">Approvers</span><br>
<div id="approvers">
</div>
<div>
  <form id="addApprover">
    <input type="email" id="approver" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="submit" class="button blueButton" value="Add">
  </form>
</div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="center">
<span id="startButton" class="button redButton">Create Workflow</span>
</div>  
</div>
```

I'd like to know how to take the html,head,title,body,pm and convert to the div and span ID that GAS wants.

I'm willing to work for it if someone wants to point me in the right direction. 
Why would I use one over the other? 
CSS can look at the whole div id #wrapper and apply across everything right?
Is there a direct translation?

It looks like the span is text, and the form documents are setup such as to retain/record information.

Pretty lost here.

Comment: Go to my profile page, and email me if you want.  I'll tell you what documentation I like for HTML.

Comment: What exactly do want to accomplish with the html/head/body markups? Which functions and properties? Mostly can be accomplished with Javascript without using those tags, other functions like setting title google built a function for it. Also, for information, CAJA is the responsible for eliminating those tags, if you wanna know more about it see [Google CAJA](https://developers.google.com/caja/).

Answer (score 0):

You can start with deleting the `<HTML>` tags.  Although, it seems like I've used those without any problems in the past.  Google may just automatically strip them out or ignore them.  I don't know.  But I don't think it's any big deal.

There is nothing in the `<head>` tags.

```
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
```

That's just empty markup.  So, it's not doing anything.  Just delete it.